# Relation between $\operatorname{depth}(R)$ and $\operatorname{depth}(R/xR)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, krull-dimension

Let $(S,\mathfrak m)$ be a local regular ring, $I\subset \mathfrak m$ an ideal and $x\in \mathfrak m\setminus I$.

If $x$ is regular on $R=S/I$, then $\operatorname{depth}(R/xR)=\operatorname{depth}(R)-1$ and
$\dim(R/xR)=\dim(R)-1$.

Also, without any conditions on $x$, we have $\dim(R/xR)\geq \dim(R)-1$.

My question is the following: In general, is it true that $\operatorname{depth}(R/xR)\geq \operatorname{depth}(R)-1$?

Comment: Just a quick comment which you might very well know already, the first three assertions: $depth(R/xR)=depth(R)−1$, $dim(R/xR)=dim(R)−1$ and $dim(R/xR)\geq dim(R)−1 $ have nothing to do with $S$ being regular and $R$ being a quotient of a regular local ring. In full generality for $A,\frak{m}$ local Noetherian, $M$ a finite $A$-module, $x_1,…,x_r\in\frak{m}$ you have that $dim(M/(x_1,…,x_r)M)≥dim(M)−r$. If further more $x_1,\dots,x_r$ is a regular sequence, then we have equality and also $depth(M/(x_1,\dots,x_r)M)=depth(M)-r$.